# Asp .net MVC pagination using button tag

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm using an MVC application and trying to do pagination.

This code works well:

```
@Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("About",    new { page, sortOrder = ViewBag.CurrentSort, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter }))
```

But i dont want buttons with numbers 1,2,3...

I just want to display '<<' '>>' button for moving back and forth using:

```
<div class="col-xs-4">
<button type="button" class="pull-right btn btn-sm btn-default"><i class="icon-budicon-175"></i></button>
<button type="button" class="pull-right btn btn-sm btn-default"><i class="icon-budicon-176"></i></button>
</div>
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can define custom render options in the PageListPager parameters.

```
@Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("About", new { page, sortOrder = ViewBag.CurrentSort, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter }), new PagedListRenderOptions { LinkToFirstPageFormat = "<<", LinkToPreviousPageFormat = "<", LinkToNextPageFormat = ">", LinkToLastPageFormat = ">>" })
```